# undefined reference to `pthread_create'

Tags: c++, makefile, pthreads

I have client server code. LinServer.cpp using pthread to continuously listen client. I created make file to compile all togather:

```
all: LinServer LinClient

    LinServer:
    g++ LinServer.cpp -o LinServer -pthread

    LinClient:
    g++ LinClient.cpp -o LinClient -pthread
```

I also tried with -lpthread but same error:

```
LinServer.cpp:(.text+0x29b): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
LinServer.cpp:(.text+0x2a7): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [LinServer] Error 1
```

Any idea what's the problem here?

Comment: to execute make file i use "make" command

Comment: -1 for not using "-Wall" :)

Comment: can you please elaborate@ kfsone

Comment: the cure in the supposed duplicate is claimed to not work -- now what?

Comment: @user2500861: Shouldn't your compiler command line to have `-lpthread` (note the letter "L") instead of `-pthread`?

Comment: @yzt : I already tried with what you said. That also does not make any diff

Comment: @user2500861: Try writing the smallest possible program that uses pthreads and see whether this link problem occurs there. If so, then post that code and your compiler command line and then maybe people would be able to help you. Remember that you have to help us help you!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should use `-lpthread` not `-pthread`.

Comment: plus one should make sure the order is correct: it must go in command line after the object file in command line

Comment: In makefile I was making mistake, I need to include -lpthread that I was missing!

Comment: @pmod I tried it and you are right, but I'm curious about why? Thanks.