# C++ Linux Error Loading Shared Library `undefined symbol: pthread_create`

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, pthreads, shared-libraries

I have created a library that compiles well and everything.
The library file is "libTextSearch.so"

Inside the library, it creates a `thread`. I am using C++11 threads for this:

```
TextSearch::TextSearch(){
    std::thread t(&TextSearch::ThreadProc, this);
    t.detach();
}
```

As I said, the library compiles and I have the `libTextSearch.so` file.

I am trying to load the library in a different application:

```
void* handle = dlopen("libTextSearch.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if(!handle){
    //std::cout << "\n  Failed to load libTextSearch.so\n\n";
    fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
    return 1;
}
```

I have the package copied to `/usr/lib` already. This is the output I get:

```
dlopen failed: /usr/lib/libTextSearch.so: undefined symbol: pthread_create
RUN FINISHED; exit value 1; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

I have looked up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264984/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create). I think it is related, but I have no idea of applying that to my situation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `dlopen` `thread` library beforehand with `RTLD_GLOBAL`

```
void* handlePthread = dlopen("libpthread.so.0", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_LAZY);
if(!handlePthread ){
    //std::cout << "\n  Failed to load libpthread.so.0\n\n";
    fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is what i had: `dlopen failed: libpthread.so.0: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument`

Comment: @Everyone EDITED, test open it with `| RTLD_LAZY` please

Comment: THANK YOU! Fixed all my problems

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly be sure since I don't know how you are building this project, or how libTextSearch.so is built, but you need to link against libpthread somehow when generating libTextSearch. Typically in your build environment you would supply -lpthread as an argument to dynamically link to it.

```
gcc -c testsearch.cpp -lpthread -o textsearch.o
```

for example

Comment: Thanks this resolved the loading issue, however, i am facing another issue with `std::thread t(&TextSearch::ThreadProc, this);`. It causes runtime error as it doesnt like being treated not as `pthread`. Any clue?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Rama's answer fixed everything for me

Comment: @Everyone Happy coding friend